# Instantiate the chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg chaincode registration failed: container exited with 254

### this is peer-base.yaml

```
version: '2'

services:

  peer-base:

    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest

    environment:

      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock

      # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same

      # bridge network as the peers

      # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

      #- CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=composer_default

      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO

      #- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG

      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true

      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true

      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false

      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true

      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt

      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key


      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt

    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer

    command: peer node start


  orderer-base:

    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest

    environment:

      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO

      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0

      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file

      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer

/orderer1.genesis.block

      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP

      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp

      # enabled TLS

      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true

      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key

      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer

/tls/server.crt

      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]

      - ORDERER_KAFKA_TOPIC_REPLICATIONFACTOR=1

      - ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true

      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer

/tls/server.crt

      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer

/tls/server.key

      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]

    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric

    command: orderer
```

#### docker-compose-base .yaml

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

version: '2'

services:

  orderer1.example.com:
    container_name: orderer1.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: orderer-base
    volumes:
        - ../channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer1.genesis.block
        - ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer1.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
        - ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer1.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
        - orderer1.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
      - 7050:7050

  peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.org1.example.com:8051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer0.org1.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    ports:
      - 7051:7051

  peer1.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org1.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:8051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:8052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org1.example.com:8051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer1.org1.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production

    ports:
      - 8051:8051

  peer0.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org2.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org2.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:9051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:9051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:9052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:9052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org2.example.com:9051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.org2.example.com:10051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer0.org2.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    ports:
      - 9051:9051

  peer1.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org2.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org2.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org2.example.com:10051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:10051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer1.org2.example.com:10052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:10052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org2.example.com:10051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org2.example.com:9051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer1.org2.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer1.org2.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer1.org2.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    ports:
```

Now i am not able to instantiate the code on the channel

```
chaincode instantiate -o orderer1.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer1.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["init","a", "100", "b","200"]}' -P "AND ('Org1MSP.peer','Org2MSP.peer')"

## the error is 
Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg chaincode registration failed: container exited with 254

      - 10051:10051
CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=composer_default

I have commented the above environment variable ,but after uncommenting the above environment variable the error still persisits 

the error is :
```

error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg chaincode registration failed: container exited with 254

Comment: Please format the code in your answer to make it more readable. Also, add some more context about what the relevant setting does, and remove the ones that aren't relevant. In other words, creating a minimal, reproducible example will make it easier for us to help you

Comment: done if you want more files i can post

Comment: Try checking logs of your containers (orderer and peer) and see if you can find something more informative there. Also double check the chaincode if you have made any changes in the chaincode because it seems there is some error in your chaincode.